# Php ul li foreach group similar

Tags: php

Using this array

```
array(
    array('status'=>1, 'name'=>'James Wah'),
    array('status'=>1, 'name'=>'James Weh'),
    array('status'=>2, 'name'=>'James Wih'),
    array('status'=>2, 'name'=>'James Woh'),
    array('status'=>2, 'name'=>'James Wuh'),
)
```

How could i output it like this

```
  James Wah  James Weh  James Wih 
  James Woh  James Wuh
```

Using only a single foreach() and has two

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, now it displays diff group of status :

```
$status = $data[0]['status'];
echo "<ul>";
foreach($data as $value) {
    if($status != $value['status'])
        echo "</ul><br /><ul>";
    echo "<li>".$value['name']."</li>";
    $status = $value['status'];
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ul = '<ul>';
foreach($arr as $v) {
 $ul.='<li>'.$v['name'].'</li>';
}
$ul.='</ul>';
```

That would be an easy solution, i dont think it is possible with just one foreach because implode does not work here because the glue has to be appended before and after

```
$sortbyStatus = array();
foreach($arr as $v) {
 $sortbyStatus[$v['status']][] = $v['name'];
}

$uls='';
foreach($sortByStatus as $vals) {
 $uls.'<ul>';
 foreach($vals as $v) {
   $uls.='<li>'.$v.'</li>';
}
 $uls.='</ul>;
}
```

}

Comment: The first 2 must be separated from the rest of the 3 because it has a different status.

Comment: I need short code like user 'dakshbhatt21' but it still not the right logic.

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($statuses as $status) {
echo "<li>". $status['name'] . "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

**Update:**

You can use a `$count` variable for creating the separation. Example:

```
$count = 0;
echo "<ul>";
foreach($statuses as $status) {
    if($count==2){
    echo "<li>". $status['name'] . "</li><br/>"; 
    }
    else{
    echo "<li>". $status['name'] . "</li>";
    }
    $count++;
}
echo "</ul>";
```

**Updated Output:**

```
• James Wuh
• James Weh
• James Wih

• James Woh
• James Wuh
```

Codepad: http://codepad.org/NyLIAUNI

Updated: http://codepad.org/xhmlCwXW

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first 2 must be separated from the rest of the 3 because it has a different status.

Comment: It must have two <ul>

Comment: Well, then use two loops. We're not here to create scripts for you. Please read the documentation and modify it according to your requirements. :)